# Use of Constraint Layout for developing TV android Apps

Tags: android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout, android-relativelayout, android-tv, viewgroup

I want to know why [android developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/layouts.html#structure) is recommending to use view groups such as `Relative Layout` or `Linear Layout` to arrange views for developing TV Android Apps and not the current standard i.e. `Constraint Layout`.

Is there any specific reason for it? I need some thoughts on that.